# Implemented queue using two stacks. What is the complexity of this code below O(1) or O(N)?. This is a leetcode question

Tags: java, queue, stack, time-complexity

I implemented queue using two stacks. What is the complexity of this code below: O(1) or O(N)? This is a *leetcode* question.

```
class MyQueue {

Stack<Integer> input;
Stack<Integer> output;
    public MyQueue() {
        
        input= new Stack<>();
        output= new Stack<>();
    }
    
    public void push(int x) {
        input.push(x);
    }
    
    public int pop() {
        int val=peek();
        output.pop();
        return val;
    }
    
    public int peek() {
        if(output.isEmpty()){
        while(input.isEmpty()==false)
        output.push(input.pop());
        
        }
        return output.peek();
    }
    
    public boolean empty() {
        
        return input.isEmpty() && output.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code? What is N? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to confirm the time complexity of push and pop operations

Comment: your code's push operation is O(1), and pop operation is O(N). since if there were n elements pushed first, and then when pop is called, you will need to move `n-1` elements to your output stack.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity for your `push` operation is O(1).
The time complexity for your `pop` operation, which depends on your `peek` method is O(N). Since, you need to move n-1 elements from one stack to another and then get the queue's first element, time complexity is O(N).

As additional, info, if you want O(1) for both operations, you could implement using a doubly-linked list.